# What the heck is a Glorkum?

Tags: nethack

So I'm still here playing Nethack, trying to unlock Wizard Mode, and I get to my inevitable death early on in the game.

The twist?
[image: Everything I had equipped has become a Glorkum.]

Google has nothing for me, referring only to "gorkums".

So, what I'm asking here is, **what on God's green earth is a Glorkum, and why have my items turned into them?**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`glorkum` is part of a [debug message](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Source:NetHack_3.4.3/src/objnam.c#line470) used for an object of unknown type in `xname`, the function Nethack uses to figure out what an object should be called. If you see it, you've encountered a bug.

Comment: The source-code is documented almost line-by-line in a wiki!?  Jesus, that is a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft they've had many years to get all that information catalogged, it would not be surprising if the tooling behind it was sophisticated enough to not be a nightmare.

Comment: @Seiyria: If you look at the history, it looks like there is no tooling, it was all done by hand.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: NetHack went twelve years without a new release up until a year ago.  At the time the wiki contributors added those comments, the problem of maintenance must have been purely hypothetical.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft the pace of development has always been rather slow, and has only gotten slower in the new millennium — an average of one release per year in the past 30 years, and only six since 2000. There aren't a million patch revisions to annotate :)